The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row
I have a procedure to store stored procedure usage stats but I am encountering issues using the MERGE statement:
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcedureUsageStats]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @command NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @command = '
    USE [?];
    MERGE [Db1].[dbo].[table1] AS target
    USING (
        SELECT 
            db_name() AS DataBaseName,
            v.object_id AS Object_ID,
            v.name AS StroredProcName,
            v.create_date,
            v.modify_date,
            ps.last_execution_time AS LastExecutionTime,
            v.type,
            v.type_desc
        FROM 
            sys.procedures v
        LEFT JOIN 
            sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats ps
            ON v.object_id = ps.object_id
    ) AS source
    ON (target.Object_ID = source.Object_ID)

    -- If the stored procedure doesn''t exist in the target table, insert it
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
        INSERT ([DataBaseName], [Object_ID], [StroredProcName], [create_date], [modify_date], [LastExecutionTime], [type], [type_desc])
        VALUES (source.DataBaseName, source.Object_ID, source.StroredProcName, source.create_date, source.modify_date, source.LastExecutionTime, source.type, source.type_desc)

    -- If the stored procedure exists in the target table and source.LastExecutionTime is not NULL, update the LastExecutionTime
    WHEN MATCHED AND source.LastExecutionTime IS NOT NULL THEN
        UPDATE SET 
            target.LastExecutionTime = source.LastExecutionTime;
    '

    EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command;
END;

I am then getting this error:

Msg 8672, Level 16, State 1, Line 20
The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.

There are duplicate object_IDs
What am I missing?

Shouldn't DataBaseName be part of the MERGE join? object_ids aren't unique per server you know

print your dynamic SQL then debug it statically

As you are running this on each database you probably should have something in the join condition onto sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats using database_id to make sure you are only matching the database you are currently interested in and not getting results for procedures with the same object_id in different databases

Duplicate on [dba.se] see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46636/which-is-the-uniqueness-level-of-object-id The issue is that object_id is only unique per database, so you need to merge on DB_ID() as well

There are multiple issues not just one. The join on sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats should include database_id as otherwise it could be bringing back stats for different procs than the one it is being joined to in sys.procedures. It should use aggregation to get the MAX in the event of multiple cached plans.  The join onto [Db1].[dbo].[table1] should include DataBaseName to avoid blindly overwriting data with content from other databases


The view returns one row for each cached stored procedure plan, and
the lifetime of the row is as long as the stored procedure remains
cached.

sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats
So if you have a proc with two cached plans, you'll match the target twice, and try to update twice.  As the other answer suggests, you'll need to modify the query to return one row per object_id.

try:
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcedureUsageStats]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @command NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @command = '
    USE [?];
    MERGE [Db1].[dbo].[table1] AS target
    USING (
        SELECT 
            ''' + DB_NAME() + ''' AS DataBaseName,
            v.object_id AS Object_ID,
            v.name AS StoredProcName,
            v.create_date,
            v.modify_date,
            MAX(ps.last_execution_time) AS LastExecutionTime, -- Use MAX to avoid duplicates
            v.type,
            v.type_desc
        FROM 
            sys.procedures v
        LEFT JOIN 
            sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats ps
            ON v.object_id = ps.object_id
        GROUP BY 
            v.object_id, v.name, v.create_date, v.modify_date, v.type, v.type_desc -- Ensure no duplicates
    ) AS source
    ON (target.Object_ID = source.Object_ID)

    -- If the stored procedure doesn''t exist in the target table, insert it
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
        INSERT ([DataBaseName], [Object_ID], [StoredProcName], [create_date], [modify_date], [LastExecutionTime], [type], [type_desc])
        VALUES (source.DataBaseName, source.Object_ID, source.StoredProcName, source.create_date, source.modify_date, source.LastExecutionTime, source.type, source.type_desc)

    -- If the stored procedure exists in the target table and source.LastExecutionTime is not NULL, update the LastExecutionTime
    WHEN MATCHED AND source.LastExecutionTime IS NOT NULL THEN
        UPDATE SET 
            target.LastExecutionTime = source.LastExecutionTime;
    '

    EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command;
END;

added grouping and aggregation with MAX(ps.last_execution_time) to make sure each object_id is unique by selecting the maximum last_execution_time for each object_id

The above proc is giving an error below:
Msg 164, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.
